# Auto deployment from bare Git repo to Apache

Tags: server, apache2, git

I am configuring a Ubuntu Server for our project now, Gitolite and Apache are working now without any problem and they are on same server, What I want right now is deploy Git repository to Apache automatically after git push.

I am looking at hooks now, however, when I do a `git pull` in Apache's directory `/var/www/project_name` just want to test if my shell script will work, the server always asks me for git user's password and gives me an fatal error message saying

```
/project_name.git does not appear to be a git repository
Could not read from remote repository.
```

Did any one have this problem before? or has better idea of auto deploying bare git repo to Apache? This is my first time configuring Ubuntu server, any advice and suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

I put my web content in `/var/www/project_name` directory,
and my git repository in `/home/git/repositories/project_name.git`.

Comment: What hook are you using now?

Comment: I am using **post-receive**.